# A pair of 'self-signing' hashing functions?

Tags: hash

Does a pair of (hashing) functions for which

[image]

where neither g(x) nor f(x) are constants exists?

Comment: Defining f as "take the last <output size of g> bytes of the input" works with arbitrary g. Another variant for f is "take everything except the last <output size of g> bytes of the input and feed it to g".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes, it is obvious. But I am earching rather pair of "cyclic" hashing functions (it can be also  ONE function : f(x) = f(x+f(x)), f(x) != x and f(x) is not constant)

Comment: @miniBill A way to guarantee the integrity of message and its signature

Comment: And how would your equation do that?

Comment: @miniBill for given message m and hash h(m) = x, there is function f which outputs f(m + x) = x. If you are asking for practical use, there is probably any.

Comment: Such a question would fit much better on the new https://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, possibly (but not clearly) about cryptography, but has no application to security.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

- g(x)=x, f(x)=x/2
- g(x)=x^2, f(x) = 1/4 * (sqrt(1+4*x)-1)^2
- g(x)=x^n, f(x) = RootOf(Z^n+Z-x)^n

Comment: This isn't a cryptographic hash (which is all the hashes we care about on [security.se]).

Comment: As you yourself pointed out above, this question appears to be a mathematics question, though it may have some security application.

Having no further information, I answered the question as stated; making unstated assumptions is as bad a practice in security as it is in science.